# How to bind json data to Looping Selector for windows phone 8

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, loopingselector

I'm developing windows phone 8 application . And using the Looping Selector functionality for bind list of city name.

I get city name list in json format.

Now i need to bind the result to looping selector as data source

**XAML CODE**

```
 <DataTemplate x:Key="NumberTemplate">
                <Grid>
                    <TextBlock 
                        Text="{Binding }" 
                        FontSize="54" 
                        FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilySemiBold}" 
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                        VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>

  <toolkit:LoopingSelector 
            x:Name="loopselector"
            Grid.Column="1" 
            Margin="12" 
            Width="128" 
            ItemSize="128,128" 
            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource NumberTemplate}">

            <toolkit:LoopingSelector.DataSource>
                <local:NumbersDataSource Minimum="0" Maximum="50" />
            </toolkit:LoopingSelector.DataSource>
        </toolkit:LoopingSelector>
```

**CS CODE**

```
 public void Citybind()
    {
        try
        {

            string city_nameurl = "http://xxxxxxx.yyyyyy";
            WebClient city_namewc = new WebClient();

            city_namewc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(city_nameurl), UriKind.Relative);
            city_namewc.DownloadStringCompleted += city_namewc_DownloadStringCompleted;
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }

    void city_namewc_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            var city_name = e.Result;
            loopselector.ItemTemplate = city_name; /* Error Cannot convert string to system.windows.dataTemplat*/
 }
```

Comment: so, what have You tried so far?

Comment: @kamiccolo I try with above code. but i don't know how to use city_name as loopingselector Itemsource

Answer (score 0):

You can use a popular Json converter library NewtonSoft.Json for this purpose. Just add it to your project from Nuget package manager in visual studio. Then in your city_namewc_DownloadStringCompleted handler, write something like this :

var city_name = e.Result;
ObservableCollection cityList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject>(city_name);

loopselector.ItemTemplate = city_name;
loopselector.ItemSource = cityList;

This code snippet assumes that your json is just a plain list of strings. If it is different, then you need to adjust the type <> you provide to JsonConvert for deserialization. Hope this helps!

Comment: I got error "The type or namespace name 'ObservaleCollection' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly "reference?)

Comment: Use this namespace : System.Collections.ObjectModel. This contains ObservableCollection

Comment: I add it. but still same error come.I check in net about this problem they tell add windowsbase dll in assemply. i'm unable to add this dll in to my assemply

Comment: Read about it here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ms668604(v=vs.105).aspx. It should be available by default.